# How to refer to S3 objects that have spaces using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using aws cli, if I have an object in my s3 bucket (test-bucket33677) called "Level Up.jpg", how do I refer to it in the cli when it has a space in the middle? I want to put it in a test directory

aws s3 cp s3://test-bucket33677/Level Up.jpg test-directory/

Something like this

Answer (score 1):

By using quotes on the command line, just like you would do for local files with spaces in the name:

```
aws s3 cp "s3://test-bucket33677/Level Up.jpg" test-directory/
```

---

Note that this is a function of the command line shell you are using, not an AWS CLI specific thing. Some shells may require you to use single quotes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on MacOS, so it worked when I did single quotes. Thanks! This solved an itch I was having